# Insert data into a table with foreign keys for a BookShop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and I have problems to insert data into my table for books for a book shop.

The `Book` table looks like this:

```
Id(PK)
Title
AuthorName
AuthorId (FK)
ISBN
GenreName
GenreId (FK)
```

I have insert data to the tables Author and Genre it looks like this.

`Author` table:

```
Id(Pk)
AuthorName
```

Inserted values : (1, 'Ernest Hemingway')

`Genre` table:

```
Id (PK)
GenreName
```

Inserted values : (1, 'Novels')

How can I insert a new book into the `Book` table with foreign keys from `Author` and `Genre` table?

I tried to insert values in SQL query but it doesn't work well.

```
INSERT INTO Books (Title, AuthorName, AuthorId, ISBN, GenreName, GenreId)
VALUES ('The Sun Also Rises', 'Ernest Hemingway', 1, '198560090', 'Novels', 1);
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Books_Authors_AuthorId". The conflict occurred in database "BookShop", table "dbo.Authors", column 'Id'.

[Book Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5THF.png)

[Genre Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkdzG.png)

[Author Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PMM4.png)

[Book table in sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHCDi.png)

Comment: Why are you storing `AuthorName` in the Books table, if you're storing `AuthorId`? (Same is true for `GenreName`.) This is an anti-pattern. Books should just have `Title`, `AuthorName`, `ISBN`, and `GenreId`. Insert your values in your previous tables first, then get the inserted ID's (Or existing ones, if that author already exists), and then insert your book row.

Comment: I have been thinking about that, that there is something I am doing wrong. As an admin, I want to be able to enter a book and enter the title, author, isbn and genre. I have two tables, one with author and one with genre where I enter the names, should I instead only have an id for author and genre in those tables. instead, I link the id from the two tables to the book table?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your specific table definitions, and just going by the error message, it looks as if the ID you are inserting for AuthorId in Books does not exist.

Check the Authors table to make sure that the record was successfully inserted.

As a side note, you may want to re-evaluate the design of your Books table.  You have AuthorName and Genre columns, in addition to ID columns pointing to the Author and Genre tables.  The ID columns allow you to join the Books table to the corresponding Author and Genre tables.  When you join to those tables using their ID columns in the Books table, you can pull in their details (author name, genre name, etc), negating the need for you to store the Author and Genre details in the Books table.

By storing the details columns in the Books table, you are storing redundant data across multiple tables.

Comment: Thank yoy for your help. I have edited my post and insert images on the tables.

Comment: Can you share the definitions of the foreign keys as well?

Did you check to ensure that the records actually exist in the Authors and Genre tables?